How to set specific array-constraints with the Google OR-Tools?
At the moment I am trying to solve a specific problem in which employees are voting for advanced training courses from a scale of 1 to 10. Not all courses will be offered and not every employee can participate in every course. I am trying to write a program in Java using Google OR Tools which automatically assigns two courses to the employees. A course needs at least 10 participants. Per course there is a limit of 30 participants.
I have an array
int a [id employee][employee's first course][employee's second course] 

in which there is the sum of ratings for both courses.
How can I set constraints by using a loop? For example the Sum of every column is not allowed to be bigger than 30 but must be at least 10. Otherwise the course will not exist. The ratings must be maximised.
For example:
sum of a[][i][]<=30
sum of a[][][i]<=30
sum of a[][i][]>=10
sum of a[][][i]>=10

I tried to find examples of similiar problems but I didn't find one.
I tried to find examples of similiar problems but I didn't find one.

    model.add(sum(python iteration) <= 30)

Did you mean something else ?
